# "Safe" typical dishes to order away from the tourist trail in Thailand when English is not supported?

Tags: food-and-drink, thailand, language-barrier, local-cuisine

I've found now that away from tourist areas, English is rare in Thailand both spoken and on menus.

I've also found that some of the dishes we in the west think of as typical for Thailand don't seem to be on offer at the kinds of places that don't expect to have "farang" customers. This means "pad thai" and "tom yum" are not available.

Here in Surat Thani there are food places literally everywhere, I have tried a hawkers' stand (as it would be known in Malaysia or Singapore) and two small cafes, they had menus but in Thai only.

[image: photo of a menu in Thai]

([higher-res version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ay8Y.jpg))

So I don't want to eat what I regard as western food when I could be trying local dishes, even when they're not "fancy". I like spicy food so that's not a problem.

But there are certain ingredients I would like to avoid: organs, eyeballs, chicken feet, gizzards, intestines, rectums, dog, pigs trotters, anything alive. I've seen all of these on menus in other countries in Asia.

I'd also like to avoid anything that has a special reputation for being unclean, spoiled, or having a higher tendency to make people sick. Things like undercooked chicken and pork, things that were probably prepared many hours ago and kept warm, etc

I want to be a bit more adventurous than settling for fried rice - what really is the typical food in these kinds of eateries in Thailand?

Comment: Isn't there this google translate app that scans and translate pictures?

Comment: @Andra: Not that I know of but that would be great. Thai script is pretty intricate though. I often can't make out the details in my phrasebook.

Comment: Well there's WordLens, but as far as I know, that only supports a smattering of Eurolanguages.

Comment: @hippietrail, why are you so fearful? Don't you like [bleu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_cheese), [maroilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maroilles_cheese) and [roquefort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roquefort) french cheeses?

Comment: I love strong cheese! It's not about fear, it's about when you want to eat something satisfying but not boring and not adventurous or challenging. I may be in that mood at other times but in such a case I would ask a different question.

Comment: A dish I eat extensively when I travel to Thailand is "cow paht moo" or pork fried rice. It's easy to say, and even if you butcher it, they typically know what you mean by the context.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum: Yes! That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Very typical in this kind of eatery, but not known from Thai restaurants in Western countries. Yummy, not Western, no off-putting ingredients. It's also common at the cheap eateries here in Laos.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum with a name like "cow paht moo", I was expecting something using beef!

Comment: You do realize that sausage is often (or at least used to be) made with intestine, right? That's a very western food :)

Comment: @DoktorJ: Many, perhaps most, cultures have sausages. I don't think they were invented a single time in the west and adopted into other cultures from the west. I personally don't mind sausages with intestine skin but I don't like intestine as food which I've tried in Korea and seen offered elsewhere.

Comment: Fair on both points; I'm not necessarily saying sausage originated in Europe/the Americas, just that it's a very common food in this hemisphere, perhaps even a staple in some regions :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm "Cow paht moo" is much too close to cowpat for my taste.

Comment: If you get an English menu, just don't order anything that says "hot". "Medium" will _almost_ blow your head off.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, your fears are a little overblown.  Thai cuisine isn't quite as "freaky" as, say, some parts of China and you're unlikely to eat something exotic by accident.  Although not eating any offal at all is going to be a little limiting...  why not give it a shot and expand your horizons a bit?

At any rate, I'd start with [Wikivoyage's description of Thai cuisine](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Thailand#Eat) and try to learn the major concepts and their Thai spellings.  (Or pick up Lonely Planet's Thai phrasebook, it's rather more compact and handy for showing to staff in a pinch.)  Some major Thai food words are quite recognizable:

- ผัด (*phat*, with a hard P), "fried", means "stir-fry" and is almost always safe to eat.  The first ten or so items in your menu are all stir-fries of some kind.
- For example, ข้าวผัด (*khao phat*) is trusty old fried rice, the 2nd item priced at 35 baht on your menu. The list of words following is your options: ไก่ (*kai*) chicken (doesn't that look a bit like a chicken head?), หมู (*mu*) pork (on all fours with its snout in the ground), กุ้ง (*kung*) shrimp, etc.  Any menu item with this list of interchangeable main ingredients after it will be quite safe.
- ก๋วยเตี๋ยว (*kuay tiao*), flat rice noodles, have two little plus signs in the accents. This particular shop doesn't have any though since they do rice, not noodles.
- Put the two together and you've got tasty, tasty fried rice noodles: ก๋วยเตี๋ยวผัด
- แกง (*kaeng*) is Thai for curry, and again easy to spot thanks to the initial แ. (See the last two entries in your menu.)
- When it (almost) repeats, it's แกงเเดง (*kaeng daeng*), or red curry!

Comment: Those were not really fears, just examples of things I've actually seen on my travels in countries where I could read the menu (-: Well except there is plenty of offal and viscera here and pigs trotters.

Comment: I brought Lonely Planet's Thai phrasebook with me and it must've fallen out of my day pack yesterday )-: Compared to their other phrasebooks the Thai script is just too fine to read in typical restaurant lighting. I'm now on my fallback Lonely Planet Southeast Asia phrasebook with more limited Thai info.

Comment: I've given offal a shot before. I can eat it to win a bet or to prove I'm tough `d-;` But I don't enjoy it and at the end of a long hard day hitchhiking I want something I know doesn't disgust me.

Comment: I settled for the fried rice at that particular place because the people there could almost say it in English, but it's a bit bland to eat every time I'm off the tourist trail which is what inspired me to ask this question. But I wish I'd known red curry was on the menu! I was thinking that would be like Pad Thai and Tom Yam Gung and only in tourist places. Now I know better!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not on the menu in this particular place, and I can't actually figure out what the two last curries are... m(_ _)m  But red curry is quite popular nationwide.

Comment: @hippietrail Note, chicken is usually pronounced *gai* - *kai* is egg. Pad Thai and Tom Yum should be pretty common. Pad Gapow, Pad Keemao, Pad Seyew, Kao ('cow') Mu Gop, Gaeng Hang Le.  Som Tam and Larb ('lahp') should be available in Lao, too.   Pung Gali (the "gali" is "curry") ... (Most of these should be available at a place with that kind of menu, and safe enough.  Larb and Som Tam might be more specialized - look for carts w shredded papaya, for the latter)

Comment: @hunter2: Yes it seemed that much of what was common in tourist areas was not common at all in on-tourist areas. Now I'm in Laos with quite different food/menu challenges (-:

Comment: We have yellow curry as well which is "Mut sa mun"

Answer (score 7):

Looking at that menu and I could say you can order any of that and it's pretty safe for "Farang". You can just add "Mai ped" ไม่เผ็ด if you cannot eat spicy food.

The most common thing and probably the safest thing to eat is "Kra pow " For example, "Kra pow Gai (Chicken)", "Kra pow Moo (Pork)". And that's what Thai people eat everyday as well.

If you like curry the correct way to say is "Paneng " which is kaeng daeng or red curry. If you ask for kaeng daeng you might get something else. Or if you like Thai green curry, you should ask for "Kaeng kaew whan " แกงเขียวหวาน.

Something to note, some restaurant cannot cook "Som Tam" You can see if they have a mortar in front of the shop. If they don't have they might be able to cook it for you but it will not be good. That's how we look for when to ask Som Tam.